# CentOS 8 update mirror list not found 'Invalid release/repo/arch combination'

Tags: centos, repository, mirror

I need to define the update mirror list in my SpaceWalk system for Centos 8. I was not able to find correct update URL.

for Centos 7 I use this:

```
curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=updates'
```

same not working for CentOS 8

```
 curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=updates'
Invalid release/repo/arch combination
```

How to find the correct update mirror list for CentOS 8?

Comment: I suspect (without evidence at-hand) that CentOS is following the [RHEL8 app stream model](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/installing_managing_and_removing_user_space_components/using-appstream_using-appstream)